# Sample Spatial Data for Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial

I'm looking for sample database including spatial data.
That can be also oracle-equivalent,convertable to sql server 2008

Related : [Where can I find sample databases with common formatted data that I can use in multiple database engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068/good-databases-with-sample-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a sample database, but some sample data I used for a SQL Server 2008 presentation a while back. It's getting old now, but maybe you can find something useful there:

http://hansolav.net/blog/ResourcesFromSQLServer2008Presentation.aspx