# Sample database schema for Oracle

Tags: oracle, sample

Are there any sample databases for Oracle like AdventureWorks for MS SQL? I've searched Oracle site but didn't find any sample database.

Comment: I don't understand why ORACLE has made it so difficult to get sample database. I work on SQL Server.
I want script that can be ran as easy as AdventureWorks in MS SQL ,I don't have SQL*Plus.I am using SQL Developer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Oracle database installation includes scripts to install sample schemas.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/toc.htm)

Many online examples use the extremely simple EMP and DEPT tables.  These tables are not part of the documented schemas listed above.  Finding the script for the beloved SCOTT/TIGER schema is harder than you might think.  The `demobld.sql` used to be under the sqlplus sub-directory.  Then in 10g (I think) they moved the schema to `$ORACLE_HOME/admin/rdbms/scott.sql`.  In 11gR2 it's moved again, to `$ORACLE_HOME/admin/rdbms/utlsampl.sql`.

Comment: The linked content is missing.

Comment: @IainElder - I guess Oracle is having a re-org of their docs prior to the launch of version 12c.  I've now fixed the broken link.

Answer (score 5):

This question can be of some help(?).

[Good Databases with sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068/good-databases-with-sample-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can run [Oracle Live SQL online](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000) without Oracle installed. Menu contains:

- SQL Worksheet
- My Session
- Schema. Includes SCOTT, HR, Order Entry (OE) and others.
- Quick SQL
- My Scripts
- Code Library

Contains a search function, scripts, and tutorials.