# MySQL: Where to find sample database with large text content?

Tags: mysql, string-matching, sql-like

For a college assignment I need to run an experiment related to MySQL. I have chosen to compare the performance of LIKE to MATCH AGAINST in the context of searching text fields.

The MySQL sample "Employees" DB was recommended to us but it doesn't really have any text fields with long text values. I'm of the opinion that i'd need something along the lines of a paragraph of text for each record to give decent results. I guess something like a paragraph about each employees background would be ideal. BUT, there are approximately 300k employees in that database.

Also, i'm guessing that the text values would want to be pretty distinct for each employee. Couldn't just use the same few for all employees.

Am I right in my assumptions and if so. Are there any other sample databases out there that would suit me?

Any ideas?

Comment: I just came across a similar question in the right hand pane. One answer suggests using the wikipedia dumps. Checking out now.

Comment: Did you find a sample dataset?

Comment: @BenSwinburne Hi, yes, I did.. Went with the Wikipedia dumps.. Lot's of text there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try any of the following links

- [Library of free data models](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm)
- [Wikimedia dumps in xml and sql form](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/)
- MySQL documentation [#1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employee.html) [#2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this previous post. One of those dataset HAS to be in mysql if not you can use www.talend.com to load it into your application.

[Where can I find sample databases with common formatted data that I can use in multiple database engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068/good-databases-with-sample-data)