# How to convert complex json dataset to be used in D3.js?

Tags: json, d3.js, dataset

I am learning D3.js and want to find some datasets to graph it. Is such kind of dataset is appropriate for the use with D3.js https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/api/views/54rh-89p8/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

It seems that data is presented as array without properties -- properties are stored separately in the meta section. Can I convert such data to be used in D3.js? If not, may you please direct me to some resource of simple datasets I can test in D3. Thanks

Comment: you can work with that array, but I'd suggest you to use a simpler csv or tsv for the beginning, it just makes things easier to understand

Comment: Thanks. Please, can you give me a link to an easy one. I've been searching WorldBank, data.gov. Only complex one with multiple files and I can't wrap my head around them

Comment: relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068/where-can-i-find-sample-databases-with-common-formatted-data-that-i-can-use-in-m

 or here: http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climateData/hourlydata_e.html?timeframe=1&Prov=ON&StationID=52641&hlyRange=2014-10-15%7C2015-05-11&Year=2015&Month=5&Day=11

 you can download the file as csv, which then will be surely easier to use than that json imo